# non www to www, tailing slashes, non https to https and friendly URL's

Tags: .htaccess

Hi getting a little stuck with my .htaccess file rules.

I have set up non https redirects to https (this works):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I have set up non www to www (this works):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have set up so it always adds trailing slashes to urls (this adds a trailing slash to thank you.php):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Redirects (not working):

```
RewriteRule ^thank-you/?$ thank-you.php [L]
RewriteRule ^thank-you.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/thank-you/ [L]
```

What should happen is if someone goes to any address that not www or not http they are redirected to https and www.

whet the file thank-you.php is accessed it should redirect to /thank-you/

if someone accessed /thank-you it should redirect to /thank-you/

getting a little stuck as the URL re writings are not working but look like they should.

thanks in advance

full code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^thank-you/?$ thank-you.php [L]
RewriteRule ^thank-you.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/thank-you/ [L]
```

Now whats strange is this code redirects /thank-you.php to /thank-you/ but does not redirect /thank-you to /thank-you/ i think something is clashing:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^thank-you/?$ thank-you.php [L]
RewriteRule ^thank-you.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/thank-you/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

i got round my issue with the bellow:

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

php:

```
function CheckUrl ($s) { // Get the current URL without the query string, with the initial slash
$myurl = preg_replace ('/\?.*$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //If it is not the same as the desired URL, then redirect
if ($myurl != "/$s") {Header ("Location: /$s", true, 301); exit;}
}

$producturl = "thank-you/";
CheckUrl ($producturl); //redirects the user if they are at the wrong place
```